# Alternate RPM to download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm

Tags: mysql, rpm

Currently http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm is not working. Is there an alternate? I am needing to install mysql5.5.

Thanks

Odd: Ok so I use this following tutorial Fri without any problems.

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-mysql-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

But now when i tired to use the CentOS 6 Mysql5.5 rpm it says can not find so i found another copy of epel-release-6.5.noarch.rpm and it does not have mysql5.5 in it?

Any thoughts?

Comment: http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can get it via this URL:

http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/Fedora//epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-6.noarch.rpm